# c# Mvc 3 Tempdata Dictionary?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my mvc3 project, I keep Dictionary in Tempdata Dictionary.

```
TempData[ViewDataKeys.ItemsAdd] = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

When Ajax request i add items to `TempData[ViewDataKeys.ItemsAdd]`.
It is updated but when i remove items from `TempData[ViewDataKeys.ItemsAdd]` it is not updated.

after remove one items from `TempData[ViewDataKeys.ItemsAdd]` , it is null.

```
 private void RemoveFrom(int Uid)
    {
        if (TempData[ViewDataKeys.ItemsAdd] == null)
        {
            TempData[ViewDataKeys.ItemsAdd] = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        }
        var a= (Dictionary<int,int>)TempData[ViewDataKeys.ItemsAdd];
        a.Remove(Uid);
        TempData[ViewDataKeys.ItemsAdd] = a;
    }


        private void AddTo(int Uid)
    {
        if (TempData[ViewDataKeys.ItemsAdd] == null)
        {
            TempData[ViewDataKeys.ItemsAdd] = new Dictionary<int,int>();
        }

        var a= (Dictionary<int,int>)TempData[ViewDataKeys.ItemsAdd];
        a.Add(Uid, Uid);
        TempData[ViewDataKeys.ItemsAdd] = a;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Whenever `TempData` is read the value it contains is returned and then it's removed from TempData. TempData actually uses the standard `Session` object but the difference is when you read a value the TempData object is removed from the session.

Generally it's only to be used for redirects or something you need to persist to the next page load.

Comment: But when i add items it is ok.

Comment: Yeah, you can add an item but next time you read the item it's gone. If you want a persistent storage then you should use `Session`

Comment: Sorry, I should make that more clear. Next time you read the item TempData returns the value it has for it and *then* removes it.

Comment: I know what u say, I put this code in view. For update Tempdata var a= (Dictionary<int,int>)TempData[ViewDataKeys.ItemsAdd];
TempData[ViewDataKeys.ItemsAdd] = a;

Comment: That should work fine. But if you read it once and then read it again the second read will always be null.